# Apply surround with code snippet to number of items?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

Is there a way to apply the surround with code snippet to number of items?
for example lets say I have number of hyperlink items and I want to have each one within a `<li> </li>.`
Can I select them and have each surrounded within a `li` tag?

For exampe : given

```
<a href="" >a</a><a href="" >a</a><a href="" >a</a><a href="" >a</a>
```

after invoking the code snipped for number of '`<a>`' tag items the result should be :

```
<li><a href="" >a</a></li><li><a href="" >a</a></li><li><a href="" >a</a></li>
```

Comment: This is a little bit unclear: `way to apply the surround with code snippet to number of items`

Comment: @Adel : Updated the question, tx